# Find all folders with specific files in them?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

This is on Windows-7.

I need to find all folders with specific files in them and list them preferably in Explorer. Is it at all possible, I seem to have hard time figuring this. This probably can be done from cmd or powershell, but I would prefer to have it done from within Explorer.

The search criteria is simply "all folders containing files with extension .ini".

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Computer (aka My Computer)
2. Navigate to c:\folder
3. In the upper right, you will see a search box, with gray wording: Search folder
4. input: *.ini and press enter

You will now see of all ini files in this directory and it's subdirectories.

Comment: Well, this far I got myself, but this gives me the list of files. What I need is a list of directories containing those files in search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve your problem using PowerShell. I am not home at the moment and have no access to PowerShell, so I can check this solution inspired by [this page](http://subjunctive.us/2008/04/01/powershell-file-search/) at a later time only.

```
dir -recurse | ?{$_.name -match “^*.ini$”} | sort name | ft directory
```

I can check up on the correctness of the answer later.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.ini -Recurse -Force -ea Silent | Select DirectoryName
```

[image]